# How to create a Docker image by downloading an ISO using Packer?

Tags: docker, packer

It is possible to create images from scratch using Packer by downloading an ISO from the internet.

**Aim:** to create Docker images by downloading an ISO using Packer

**Attempts**

*Attempt 1*

It is possible to import a Docker image

```
[username@hostname]$ cat docker.json 
{
    "builders":[{
        "type": "docker",
        "image": "ubuntu",
        "export_path": "image.tar"
    }]
}
```

using Packer:

```
[username@hostname packer]$ packer build docker.json 
docker output will be in this color.

==> docker: Creating a temporary directory for sharing data...
==> docker: Pulling Docker image: ubuntu
==> docker: Starting docker container...
==> docker: Exporting the container
==> docker: Killing the container: 6e0e5488d8b4f97667123ea965a561c91122f3efc6ef4b86a7c40560714d6577
Build 'docker' finished.

==> Builds finished. The artifacts of successful builds are:
--> docker: Exported Docker file: image.tar
```

*Attempt 2*

Changing the builder type of a packer.json that is used to create a virtualbox image to `docker` results in:

```
[username@hostname]$ packer build docker-scratch.json 
docker output will be in this color.

15 error(s) occurred:

* unknown configuration key: "boot_command"
* unknown configuration key: "boot_wait"
...
* unknown configuration key: "vboxmanage"
* unknown configuration key: "virtualbox_version_file"
```

**Problem**

However, if a docker image needs to be created several base images could be downloaded, but is it also possible to download an ISO and to transform that to a docker image?

---

### Reference

[Basic Example: Export](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to bootstrap your own images. Check the `mkimage-*` scripts from the [contrib](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/contrib) directory.

Comment: This means that this is done without Packer? How to subsequently import it using Packer? Run packer from the parent directory where the created image resides?

Comment: Have you read any of the scripts and how they work? These scripts will allow you to create a image that is self-dependent and will not download other images when using it. From there on, you just use it as the "ubuntu" image in your example.

Comment: `sudo sh mkimage-yum.sh -y /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo centos` works perfectly and creates a centos7 box. Now I am trying to create a specific docker box, e.g. 6.3, 6.4. I have customized the script but I am unable to create such a box. Do you know whether this is possible? Have you ever created such a box?

Comment: It is a container and not a box. Yes, just create a custom yum config that points to the repos for those versions.

Comment: [I am trying to create a Docker container of a specific version of CentOS](http://serverfault.com/questions/740113/how-to-create-a-docker-container-of-a-specific-version-of-centos),